# variable reference for postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that I have to update every month and generate a new table. There are several references to this table, and I always seem to miss one. I was wondering if there is a way that I can set a local variable and reuse it through out the query. As an example:

```
    DECLARE 'table'||to_char(curent_timestamp, 'MON') ||
               to_char(current_timestanp,"YY") AS table_ref;
    CREATE TABLE table_ref AS select * FROM base_table;
    SELECT * FROM table_ref;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the context in which this is used? If you just wanted the contents, you could simply query `base_table` directly, so I assume you are trying to create a copy at a point-in-time and "timestamp" the table name? Is that correct?

Comment: Totally - the query would be more complex than that. I was just going with a simple base example.

Comment: Question should be closed because it is obsolete (see comments on answer below) and OP formulated a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37752296/3304426).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FORMAT()` and `EXECUTE` to execute your dynamic SQL, like so:

```
DO $$

DECLARE table_name TEXT;

BEGIN

   SELECT FORMAT('table%I',TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'MONYY')) INTO table_name; -- ex. tableJUN16

   EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE TABLE %I AS SELECT * FROM base_table;',table_name);

END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

This will create your new table from the `base_table` with your dynamic name.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: I'm not at my computer now, but I want to reference this table several times through out the script. Is that possible?

Comment: @windsormatic - Yea. I'll update it to suit that better.

Comment: Use %I substitution symbol in function `format` for SQL identifier. It ensure correct escaping and protection against SQL injection.

Comment: That would probably work - but I am in postgreSQL 8.2.

Comment: @windsormatic - That is a very old version. Neither `EXECUTE` nor `FORMAT` are supported in 8.2. I was suggest you add the `postgresql-8.2` tag to your question so that you can get answers specific to your version.

Comment: @Nicarus `EXECUTE` is available in PG8.2, `format()` isn't. The OP followed your advice on the tag, but made it a new question.

Comment: I did make it in a new question as I felt as though the provided answer would provide color for those that might be looking for a solution to this problem utilizing a newer version of PG.

Comment: Then you should delete this question because it is obsolete